# highstock timestamp, year 2038

Tags: timestamp, highcharts

I'm working with HighStock framework, and I have a problem with date formats Timestamp after 2038.

There are not example in the HighStock API.

I know there is maybe an answer with UTC format. But how can I use it ?

Before I used :

```
     /* $lvals[0]=>year, $lvals[1]=>day, 
return a Javascript Timestamp format (millisecond) */

    mktime(0,0,0,1,$lvals[1],$lvals[0])*1000
```

And I push it on my JSON array (I cannot use the intervals because my data are discontinuous).

So, now I need to change it. And find a function that achieves the same result by taking parameters: the number of days and years.

([Highstock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock))

Thanks!

> **Edit with DateTime solution:**

```
$date = new DateTime();

$date->setDate(2254, 1, 10); // beyond the 2038 year problem

echo $date->format('U')*1000 // Highstock allows this format
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: I solved my problem. Using DateTime PHP class.